# AWS lambda expected intended block error in Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I am following the below document to connect to Cloudwatch logs to ELK.

https://medium.com/@sohit_kumar/streaming-aws-cloudwatch-logs-to-your-own-elk-logging-solution-2bbd32f25100

I get a **"expected an indented block"** syntax error in python for this line.

> try:  logs = awslogs_handler(s, event)

Can someone help me figure this out? Not sure what im missing.

Thanks!

Comment: The entire example has incorrect indentation, not only the `try` line.

Comment: Thats true, when i moved to correcting try, i see issue with the next for statements. Is there a way to correct this? @Marcin

Comment: It has to be manually all fixed. I'm not aware of any automated way to fix that.

Comment: Got it thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use something like this:

```
try:
    logs = awslogs_handler(s, event)
```

An indent block(contains four whitespaces) are required. You can read more [here](https://medium.com/@peey/what-is-the-inconsistent-use-of-tabs-and-spaces-in-indentation-error-and-why-is-it-caused-f3bbb8b2568b#:%7E:text=When%20you%20indent%20in%20python,%2C%201%20tab%2C%20or%20whatever.)